# How do I create my own shower hose?

Tags: plumbing

I want to make a flexible 3" hose for the shower. Can someone please tell me how I can go about making my own custom size shower hose? I'm looking to make a 3 inch hose with 1/2" female swivel ends.

This picture is very similar to what I want:

[image]

I'm open to using a material as shown in the picture, or braided steel or whatever material showers hoses use.

Currently I'm using quick connects and 3" polyethylene tubing for my project, but I need something more secure and professional looking.

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: Where are you? Will this be in the line before or after the valve which turns the water on and off? That is, will it be constantly pressurized at full water pressure or will it only carry water when the water is turned on and coming out the shower?

Comment: It will only carry water when the water is turned on.

Comment: What is the type of fitting on each end? The kind of hose that you have in the picture might work if you'd get a longer one and make a loop. Maybe copper tubing with compression (nut and ferrule) connections. If you describe the overall arrangement, then it would help people to make useful suggestions. FYI the "braided stainless steel" hoses are some sort of reinforced plastic inside and the steel braiding is only protection against abrasion and maybe rodent attack I don't think these are intended for wet locations because water would be trapped between the braided steel armoring and the plast

Comment: You might be able to repurpose a flexibile tap connector with the aid of some adaptors.

Comment: I believe anything beyond quick connects and compression fittings is going to require a specialized and quite expensive crimping tool.  If you're going to make a 100 of these, it might be worth it, but for just 1, it could end up costing a few hundred dollars.

Comment: I'm not sure what 'professional looking' means - is this going to be exposed to sight when finished?

Answer (score 1):

1/2 inch pex female fittings with a piece of tube cut to length might work for your project. The ends push on and lock in place without tools other than a knife to cut the tubing.

Comment: Yes but be aware that 1/2" pex has a slightly tighter interior diameter than 1/2" copper.  I once ran 1/2" pex from a mixer valve to a tub spout and it reduced flow enough that water would come from shower head as well.

Comment: Have you ever looked at the orifices in a valve ? The valve has a much larger restriction than the pex.

Comment: I should have said mixing chamber - sorry forget the exact word but in the shower fitting it's where hot and cold come together. Usually about 2-3" in diameter.  The chamber wasn't the issue - it was the pipe diameter leaving it.